# Double separator in the path after Path.GetDirectoryName method c#

Tags: c#, .net, path, uri

I want get directory from blob absolute Uri:
https://001.blob.core.windows.net/files/11-files.trg.

For this I use **Path.GetDirectoryName** method. As result I have:
https:\\001.blob.core.windows.net\\files.

Why does a double separator appear and how to replace it with a single one?

Comment: What exact string are you expecting?  Also, the `Path` class is intended to traverse file system paths (historically on Windows with the backslash) not URIs.

Comment: I am expecting https://https://001.blob.core.windows.net/files

Comment: For extracting parts of a URL, better use the [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri) class

Comment: I understand my mistake, thanks. This method is not suitable in this case.

Comment: https is a protocol and will not work with GetDirectoryName.  GetDirectlory name will only work with a shared folder on the Network.  It looks like you machine name is 001 so if path is shared files can be found using \\001 (not https).  Try with file explorer to see if there are any shared directories on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Path.GetDirectoryName only works for relative paths, but not for URLs. So the first thing that comes to my mind is something like this:

```
var url = "https://001.blob.core.windows.net/files/11-files.trg";

var temp = new string(url.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
int index = temp.IndexOf('/');
temp = temp.Substring(index + 1 , temp.Length - index - 1);
var result = new string(temp.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(result);
//output: https://001.blob.core.windows.net/files
```